# Analytic continuation of $\zeta$

Tags: analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, analytic-continuation

It is known that$$\frac{1}{s-1} - \frac{\zeta(s)}{s} = \int_1^\infty \frac{x - [x]}{x^{s+1}} dx$$ for $Re(s) > 0.$

The last integration can provide the analytic continuation for $\zeta.$

I encouter one generalization of the situation :

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[0,1]$. If $$F(s) = s \int_1^\infty f(\{t\})t^{-s-1} dt, s = \sigma + it, \sigma >0$$ then $F(s)$ has the analytic continuation to the entire $\mathbb{C},$ where$ \{a\} = a - [a].$

This general case is for Riemann zeta if $f(x) = x.$

I want to prove this theorem, and it states just set $$A = \int_0^1 f(u) du , f_1(u) = \int_0^u (f(\{v\})-A) dv.$$
Then induction and integration by parts will yields the result, but I do not understand. At least, $F$ has different integration $(\int_1^\infty = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_n^{n+1})$ from $A$ and $f_1.$

It sounds like it is a well-known theorem, but most of the time I notice that $\zeta$ analytic continuation method is done using gamma function $\Gamma$ or Bernoulli polynomial.

I cannot find a reference with good detail to follow the steps in the proof.

Any help please ?

Comment: Thank you. I ask there already, but no response. Is this site valid to ask a question related to when I read a textbook and stuck on the proof claim in the book ? If not, I am sorry.

Comment: I didn't find your question on Math.SE, is it called like this one? This site is actually for research-level mathematics.

Comment: Usually you should wait longer for an answer there before reasking here. And you should post links in both places for people to know.

Comment: okay, sorry about that.

Comment: And this theorem is useful for the Dirichlet L-functions, or the Hurwitz zeta, or for a mix of those, for example $\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{i  n x} n^{-s}$

Answer (score 2):

*$f(\{t\})$ is a weird way to say it is $1$ periodic.*

> If $g(x)$ is $T$-periodic, then for any $a > 0$, the Mellin transform of $g(x) 1_{x > a}$ is meromorphic on the whole complex plane

- Let $g_0(x) = g(x)$ and consider the sequence of functions $$g_{n+1}(x) = \int_a^x (g_n(t) - \overline{g}_n)dt,\qquad\qquad \overline{g}_n = \frac{1}{T}\int_a^{a+T}g_n(x)dx$$
  note that all those functions $g_n(x)$ are $T$-periodic.
- Look at the Mellin transforms of $g_n(x) x^{-n}1_{x > a}$ :
  $$G_n(s) = \int_a^\infty g_n(x)x^{-s-n-1}dx$$
  Since $g_n(x) = \mathcal{O}(1)$, it converges and is analytic on $Re(s) > -n$
- Subtracting the mean value and integrating by parts :
  $$\begin{eqnarray}G_n(s) - \frac{\overline{g}_n a^{-s-n}}{s+n}&=& \int_a^\infty (g_n(x)-\overline{g}_n)x^{-s-n-1}dx \\
  &=&  (s+n+1)\int_a^\infty g_{n+1}(x)x^{-s-n-2}dx \\ &=&  (s+n+1)G_{n+1}(s)\end{eqnarray}$$
  and hence $G_{n+1}(s)$ is meromorphic on $Re(s) > \sigma \implies$ $G_{n}(s)$ is meromorphic on $Re(s) > \sigma $ too.

Overall, **$G_0(s)$ is meromorphic on $Re(s) > -n$ for every $n$, i.e. it is meromorphic on the whole complex plane**

Comment: Note that $\zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s}$ is already the Mellin transform of a **periodic distribution** : $\zeta(s)= \int_{1-\epsilon}^\infty \text{I}\Pi(x) x^{-s}dx$ where $\text{I}\Pi(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \delta(x-n)$ is the [Dirac comb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_comb)

Comment: Thank you very much for help. I have never heard about Merlin transformation. Can I think of it as a kind of special integration ? I will try to deduce it, but I wonder if it has a simpler longer, but require not much background knowledge. Or when the book says set $A = ...$ and do induction, it means this whole things.

Comment: @user117375 Here you don't need to look at the properties of the Mellin transform, except that $\int_a^\infty g(x) x^{-s-1}dx$ is analytic for $Re(s )> 0$ if $|g(x)| < C$. And $\int_1^\infty h(x) x^{-s-1}dx = \int_0^\infty h(e^t)e^{-st}dt$ so the Mellin transform of $h(x)1_{x > 1}$  is the Laplace transform of $h(e^t)1_{t > 0}$

Comment: Of course, since Dirichlet series are Mellin transforms, you need to study it in detail for understanding the theory of $\zeta(s)$

Comment: okay, thank you very much. I will try to understand that. I far more complicated than I first expect.

Comment: I am currently have introduction to analytic number theory course. It is tough, but this one is the toughest I ever seen in the book.

Comment: @user117375 Compared to the whole theory of $\zeta(s)$, what I wrote in this answer **isn't complicated**

Comment: okay, then I hope I can understand it. Thank you very much again.

Comment: Before I see your solution, I try to modify this one (page 99) http://www.math.tifr.res.in/~publ/ln/tifr01.pdf, but here it is not general function $f$. It does not explain much, and leave out various details, but the proof looks simpler. Is it because my case $f$ is general, not explicit as this one that make it looks more fuzzy ?

Comment: @user117375 p.99 I find it does the analytic continuation of $\zeta(s)$ only for $Re(s) > -1$, as $\frac{1}{s-1}-\frac{\zeta(s)}{s}  = \frac{1/2}{s}+\int_1^\infty (x-\lfloor x \rfloor - 1/2) x^{-s-1}dx$

Comment: This is exactly what I did in my answer, with $g_0(x) = x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ and $\overline{g}_0 =  \int_0^1 g_0(x)dx = 1/2$, and I made it general, with the analytic continuation to $Re(s)> -n$ for any $n$

Comment: pkay, wjat you did is the same thing but general case of what I found. Thank you very much. I study it now. Would you mind if I get stuck and ask something later ?

Comment: @user117375 stop asking one question per day :) . Two per week is the maximum, otherwise it means you didn't make your own research

Comment: k, I will try my best to do that. I know it is the best to do myself, but it often goes from nowhere to nowhere, or nowhere to get lost.